# A-star slower than dijkstra

Tags: python, python-3.x, dijkstra, a-star, maze

I have a nasty bug that I can't solve for quite some time.
I have implemented Maze Solving using A* (A-star) and Dijkstra in python and my A* is actually slower than Dijkstra.

This part is same for both:

```
    open_list={}

    dist=dict([(v, float('inf')) for v in self.adj_list])
    dist[start]=0

    parents=dict([(v,None) for v in self.adj_list])

    marked={}
    marked[start]=True
    while open_list:
        (tmp,val)=min(open_list.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])
#take current minimum from open_list, add it to closed list and
#remove it from open_list

        del open_list[tmp]

        #if we found exit
        if tmp == stop:
            path=deque([])

            while parents[tmp]:
                path.appendleft(tmp)
                tmp=parents[tmp]

            path.appendleft(start)
            return list(path)
```

A*:

```
 for v,w in self.adj_list[tmp]:
            if v not in marked:
                marked[v]=True

                dist[v]=dist[tmp]+w
                open_list[v]=dist[v]+self.h[v]

                parents[v]=tmp

            elif v in open_list:
                if dist[v] > dist[tmp]+w:#better path exists
                    dist[v]=dist[tmp]+w
                    parents[v]=tmp
                    open_list[v]=dist[v]#update value in open_list
```

Dijkstra:

```
for v,w in self.adj_list[tmp]:
            if v not in marked:
                marked[v]=True

                dist[v]=dist[tmp]+w
                open_list[v]=dist[v]

                parents[v]=tmp

            elif v in open_list:
                if dist[v] > dist[tmp]+w:
                    dist[v]=dist[tmp]+w
                    parents[v]=tmp
                    open_list[v]=dist[v]
```

As you can see, they are same(except the heuristics part in A*), but for some reason A* is slower and gets in `if dist[v] > dist[tmp]+w:#better path exists` this branch much more often. Heuristics are good, I checked multiple times

Any ideas?

If you wish to try, [here](https://github.com/wdtbd/MazeSolver) is Github repo

Comment: You *definitely* shouldn't be iterating over your entirely adjacency list. Only look up the neighbors of the nodes on the edge.

Comment: @o11c I'm not, I'm only checking neighbors of current node
`for v,w in self.adj_list[tmp]`

Comment: A* isn't guaranteed to be faster than Dijkstra.  Especially on something like a maze that's designed to be tricky, the advice given by the heursitic may be unhelpful even though the heuristic is admissible.

Comment: @MattTimmermans you were right, thanks! :)